# Quasi isomorphisms in a commutative diagram

Tags: homological-algebra

Consider a commutative diagram of complexes over a ring $R$
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
0 @>>> X @>>> Y @>>> Z \\
@. @VVfV @VVgV @VVhV \\
0 @>>> X' @>>> Y' @>>> Z'
\end{CD}$$
with exact rows. I know that the complexes  $Y$, $Y'$, $Z$, and $Z'$ are exact, hence the maps $g$ and $h$ are automatically quasi-isomorphisms. (i.e., by definition, they induce isomorphisms on the homologies).

My question is: Is the leftmost vertical map $f$ also a quasi isomorphism?

A natural attempt is to use the long exact sequences of homology modules induced by short exact sequence of complexes. However, I'm not able to conclude it.

Comment: Yes. I corrected it.

Answer (score 11):

No.

Let $X'=Y'=Z'=0$, let $\alpha:Y\to Z$ be any quasi-isomorphism between acyclic complexes whose kernel is not acyclic, and let $X=\ker(\alpha)$.

For example, if $R=\mathbb{Z}$, then $Y$ could be $\cdots\to0\to\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{\sim}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\to0\to\cdots$, with $Z=Y[1]$ and $\alpha$ the obvious map with $\ker(\alpha)$ equal to $\cdots\to0\to0\to\mathbb{Z}\to0\to\cdots$.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for your answer. But I'm working with non-zero complexes in both rows. Might it make any difference?

Comment: @H.Ali Well, you could just take the direct sum of the diagram I described with one that only involves nonzero complexes.

Comment: You are right; thank you.  Are you aware of any extra assumptions that make the answer positive?